# Angular-4 application prevents directive from loading in IE

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer

I am using an AngularJS 4 application and would like the main application directive to be rendered only when not viewed in an IE browser.

If it is IE, I would like to display a message stating that this application is not available for IE (all version of IE from 6 to 11).

IE comments are no longer supported in IE 10 onwards, so how to now do the above for all IE browsers?

Comment: so you've tried what?

Answer (score 0):

You use ua-parser-js (at [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js) or [github](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js)) to find what browser is currently being using. Once you know that you can have your directive do different thing.

Better approach would be to have two directives, one your application main directive and two, message directive. You can then determine type of browser before app loads and then set them on and off with ngIf depending upon current browser name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can this library be used with angular 4? The library seems to support version 1.x. ?

Comment: After npm-installing it on your project, you can import it as `import * ua_parser from "ua-parser-js"`. You can use the help here: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af . Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer [doesn't support the `navigator` object](https://caniuse.com/#search=navigator).

What you could simply do is

```
if (!navigator) { /* do your stuff */ }
```

I remember using it for the HTML 5 File API, works pretty well !